Detect and Manage Song Playback with Title, Author, and Cover
In javascript, how can I make chrome detect the song being played and manage it from the dedicated section for managing audio or video being played, with the cover of a song being played from a tab with title and author?

I tried searching online or asking chatgpt, but they were of no help.

Hello. I think that this is browser related issue. Your browser just reads your HTMLAudioElement source file exif data to display that widget. The song data itself must be inside the song file itself as exif ID3 tags. See https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 for more details.

You can make your own custom player instead, or look for Chrome documentation and see if the specific browser allows you to manage that widget. So far I found nothing on how to manipulate that specific overlay.

I think you're looking for the Media Session API.
Here's a quick example from that MDN documentation:
if ("mediaSession" in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: "Unforgettable",
    artist: "Nat King Cole",
    album: "The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)",
  });

  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("play", () => {
    // Code to control your player
  });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("pause", () => {
    // ...
  });
}

See also: https://web.dev/articles/media-session
